# Magento, Mage register data not set in controller action

Tags: php, magento

I have below action in controller. I want to pass the data to my phtml file with use of `Mage::register` but data are not printed in phtml.

Is there any solution for it?

Controller action method:

```
public function formAction() {
        Mage::register('feedback', 'feedback');
        return $this->_redirectReferer();
     }
```

.phtml file after action called:

```
echo Mage::registry('feedback');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Mage::register() use

```
Mage::getModel('core/session')->setFeedback("Feedback value");
```

to get feedback value use

```
    Mage::getModel('core/session')->getFeedback();
```

Comment: It's gives error : Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Model_App::getFeedback()